# superset import-dashboards KeyError: 'ZIPPED_FILE_MAX_SIZE'

Tags: import, dashboard, apache-superset, keyerror

I am running Superset as a container(pod) in Openshift and I am trying to import a dashboard into it. The dashboard is already exported as a ZIP file. I need/want to import that dashboard via CLI, not from GUI.

When I run following command in Pod's Terminal, I get ZIPPED_FILE_MAX_SIZE error, even if the exported dashboard (ZIP file) is only a size of 12 kB.

```
$ superset import-dashboards --path ./superset-exports/dashboard_export_20231023T070143.zip
logging was configured successfully
2023-10-23 07:28:31,719:INFO:superset.utils.logging_configurator:logging was configured successfully
2023-10-23 07:28:31,796:INFO:root:Configured event logger of type <class 'superset.utils.log.DBEventLogger'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/superset", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('apache-superset', 'console_scripts', 'superset')())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 357, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/superset/cli/importexport.py", line 156, in import_dashboards
    contents = get_contents_from_bundle(bundle)
  File "/app/superset/commands/importers/v1/utils.py", line 211, in get_contents_from_bundle
    check_is_safe_zip(bundle)
  File "/app/superset/utils/core.py", line 1930, in check_is_safe_zip
    if zip_file_element.file_size > current_app.config["ZIPPED_FILE_MAX_SIZE"]:
KeyError: 'ZIPPED_FILE_MAX_SIZE'
```

Can anyone please advise/help me to solve this issue? How to set or disable this check...
Thank you.
Lubos

I expected to pass this check as the file size is only 12 kB.